# How to position page numbering in footer for only where Chapters begin

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

So far I have the page numbering in header for all pages (which is fine as wanted) except for the page where chapter begins - they are left empty without page numbering.

I would like to get the page number in footer for pages where chapter begins. Is that possible ?

So far I got this which work pretty well for page numbering in headers however the page numbering are missing for chapter pages:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}                       % Sets fancy header and footer
\fancyfoot{}                            % Delete current footer settings


\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    % Page number (boldface) in left on even
% pages and right on odd pages
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}      % Chapter in the right on even pages
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}\chaptermark}     % Section in the left on odd pages

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where you redefine the `plain` page style, you wrote `\fancyfoot{}`, which makes the footer empty, since it's the plain style which is uused on chapters first pages in standard classes. Use `fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` instead.

Comment: easy way to do it - thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a standard class (there is no MWE in the question), you can remove the definition of fancypagestyle `plain`. Then the default `plain` style provided by the standard class is used on chapter pages. And this default `plain` style seems to be the desired style.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot brow

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in your preamble:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}%
\thispagestyle{plain}
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}%
\thispagestyle{plain}
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
\thispagestyle{plain}
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}%
\thispagestyle{plain}
}
\makeatother
```

This will change the default behavior of the chapter (that includes a `pagestyle{empty}` command)

Comment: I had not seen the comment of @Bernard ... and depends on the documentclass if the `pagestyle` would be `plain` or `empty` ... But this code is supposed to fix the issue anyway.

Comment: I simply added the code, but the page numbering was still empty on chapter pages - I appreciate your help, I have fixed it